# What makes this class requirement a cyclic class definition?

Tags: constraints, hacklang, cyclic

The typechecker considers this class requirement by the interface `IBase` to be cyclic:

```php
<?hh // strict
interface IBase {
    require extends Derived;
}
class Derived implements IBase {}
// Cyclic class definition : IBase Derived  (Typing[4013])
```

As I understand it, the constraint just prevents all descendants from `implements IBase` without `extends Derived`. Is there a hole with this that I'm not seeing?

#### Why do I care?

I'm interested in an interface that wants to compare against other instances of itself or its subtypes.

```php
<?hh // strict
interface Comparable<-T as Comparable<T>> {
    require extends ArtificialCeiling;
    public function compare(T $comparee): bool;
}
abstract class ArtificialCeiling implements Comparable<ArtificialCeiling> {
    abstract public function compare(ArtificialCeiling $comparee): bool;
}
```

(`this` is not the answer here, because `this` isn't sound in contravariant positions, [especially in interfaces](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7836))

Suppose now we want to accept and *store* a wrapper of `Comparable` but we don't care about what type of `Comparable` it's lugging around. Normally, we'd just parameterize with the upper bound, or `mixed` if its unconstrained.

The problem is that the upper bound for `Comparable` is `Comparable<Comparable<Comparable<...` forever, but I don't have the stamina to type that for all eternity. Without existential types like Scala or multiple constraints like `TComparable as Comparable & ArtificialCeiling`, we have to resort to something less obvious. `require extends ArtificialCeiling` would be just like a multiple constraint and, without this mysterious cyclic problem, it would be a tidy fix.

The other natural alternative is for the accepting class to append the parameter to its own parameter list as `TComparable as Comparable<TComparable>`, but that defeats the principle of not caring about `TComparable`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not an expert, but the message seems clear to me:
the definition is cyclic, because `Derived` uses `IBase` and `IBase` references `Derived`.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/other-features/trait-and-interface-requirements):

> require extends should be taken literally. The class must extend the
>   required class; thus the actual required class does not meet that
>   requirement. This is to avoid some subtle circular dependencies when
>   checking requirements.

I think the way to go is to specify the requirement for an ancestor class, and implement the interface in the non-abstract derived class(es). Or maybe just implement `compare` as a normal method in the ancestor class, instead of using a trait.